# Cannot mount data volume in Docker with Windows

Tags: docker, containers, virtualbox, virtualization, boot2docker

I am running Docker on Windows. I have succesfully build an image with command:
`docker build -t my/tag /c/Users/user/Docker/docker-php/image/`

`docker images` result:

`REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
my/tag              latest              763a2f01c832        28 minutes ago      445.8 MB
php                 5.6-cli             32d2bd1d7a19        6 days ago          444.5 MB`

Unfortunately I have a problem, when I am trying to mount data volume to image. I run:

``` docker run --rm -it -v /``pwd``:/src -w /src my/tag bash ```

(There is single backtick on `pwd`, but I don't knwo how to escape it.)

But files aren't visible in docker:

`root@3e91981ef517:/src# ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Aug 31 18:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 47 root root 4096 Aug 31 19:15 ..`

I have tried with different approach, such as:

``` docker run --rm -it -v /``pwd``:/src -w /src my/tag bash ```

(There is single backtick on `pwd`, but I don't knwo how to escape it.)

`docker run --rm -it -v /full/path/to/sources:/src -w /src my/tag bash`

`docker run --rm -it -v //full/path/to/sources:/src -w /src my/tag bash`

But every time the same result.